# Unable to edit node translation other than current language

Tags: i18n-l10n, users

On my multilingual site I seem to have problem at `admin/content` when editing a particular translation.

I have a Contact Us page, translated:

```
Contact Us [EN], node/286
Contact Us [ES], node/300
```

I don't have an explicit Path Translation set, but the nodes are bound together, in the Translate tab.

Now the problem is, that when my current language is English and I want to edit the Spanish version from the Content listing, the edit link takes me to its English version `(node/286)`. Apparently the admin overlay inherits the language prefix and forces the English translations to open.

What luckily works correctly is editing the node from within its view (by hitting the Edit tab).

Is this normal behavior?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you find a solution?

Comment: Not really. I think I came to terms with it, but it has been misleading and lead me to inadvertently destroy a couple of translations by opening improper translation.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone having this issue should read https://www.drupal.org/node/1399506.

The problem arises from the feature Language Path Checking within the Global Redirect module. Use the dev version to correct the problem.